# Power BI Dax Expression Help - Setting default slicer between dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power Bi report uses a date slicer (between) - As a default I want it to set the first date in the slicer as Monday (last week) and the last date as Friday (last week). I dont want this to be a relative date but always must be the previous Mon-Fri. I have a column in my data set that tells me which one is the 'Previous Week' as a text field. I dont know how to use this to set a default slicer value. But i also want to make sure the user can change the slicer dates and it changes as per the user request.

Example today is 01/09/2020

I want my default slicer date as : 24/08/2020 - 28/08/2020

I have two measures which gives me by last week dates:

```
DefaultSD = MINX( FILTER(Data, [WeeksFilter] = "Previous Week Only"),[Date])  

DefaultED = MAXX( FILTER(Data, [WeeksFilter] = "Previous Week Only"),[Date])
```

I assume this is possible using a DAX expression but dont know how to create this expression to populate these default values.

Please note the data is refreshed up until 01/09/2020 so there is currently data for this week but i dont want this to included in the default slicer on report load

Comment: I found no option for setting Slicer default value. This morning I was trying for a much similar implementation but no luck. You can calculate start and end dates using DAX, but can not set them to Slicer as a selected start and end date.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set slicer defaults [yet](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=39ba67cf-724e-4b6c-9906-51163749f759) but this can be achieved with [relative date filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range).

Select date in the last 1 calendar week:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work but "i also want to make sure the user can change the slicer dates and it changes as per the user request" if i add this as a page filter once i select different dates the visualizations go blank unless i clear the above filter. Is there a way this can be done automatically?

Comment: I get it but there isn't a clean way to do exactly that yet. You may be interested in some [workarounds](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Setting-the-Default-Value-of-a-Slicer/m-p/16449) though.